Matrix algebras with involutions
This question relates to Example 8.5 in Milne's Introduction to Shimura Varieties. Let me set up some notation first. Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, and $B$ over $k$ an (not necessarily commutative) algebra with $k$ in the center. We shall denote by $*$ a $k$-linear involution on $B$ ($(ab)^*=b^*a^*$ and $b^{**}=b$). Heuristically, one would like to relate this $B$ to the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear endomorphisms of an abelian variety.
Over an algebraically closed field $k$, we say $(B,*)$ of type (A) if $B$ is isomorphic to the product of matrix algebras $\operatorname{M}_n(k)\times \operatorname{M}_n(k)$ such that $(M,N)^*=(N^t,M^t)$. If the field is not algebraically closed, then we say that it is of type (A) if $B\otimes_{F_o,\rho} k^a$ is of type (A) for every morphism $\rho:F_o\rightarrow k^a$, where $F_o$ is the ring of $*$-invariants in the center of $B$.
Now, coming to the example

Let $F$ be an étale $k$-algebra of degree $2$. Thus $F$ is $k\times k$ or a field of degree $2$ over $k$, and there is a unique nontrivial involution $*$ of $F$ fixing the elements of $k$ ......  $B$ is isomorphic to a matrix algebra  over $F$ and $(B,*)$ is of type (A). These conditions imply that $B\cong \operatorname{End}_F(W)$, where $W$ is any simple $B$-module....

Firstly, from some previous discussions in the text it is clear that $F$ should be the center of the algebra $B$. What is not clear to me is part where $W$ is a simple $B$-module. Sure, if $F$ is a field, then $B\cong \operatorname{End}_F(F^n)$. But, if $F\cong k\times k$, then $B\cong \operatorname{End}_F(({k\times k})^n)=\operatorname{M}_n(k)\times \operatorname{M}_n(k)$. But $(k\times k)^n$ is not a simple $B$-algebra ($k^n$ with $B$ acting component wise is). Have I made some error?
Thanks for any helps

Such things are discussed in detail in Chapter 24 of Milne's book on Algebraic Groups.

@anon Thanks for the recommendation. I'll have a look!
